# Import Javascript file in Bottle (framework jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bottle

I have a problem when I try to run my HTML file with javascript in Bottle.
Have a look at my code:

**bottle server:**

```
from bottle import static_file
...
@route('/static/<filename>')
def static():
return static_file(filename, root='.')
...
```

**HTML file:**

```
...
<input type="text" id="time" class="datepicker" required>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-ui/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-ui/my-script.js"></script>
```

**Javascript file:**

```
$(function() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

HTML file runs correctly when I don't use Bottle (so without using `style/`) but not from Bottle. I use a method `static()` to return the url of my javascript file, this method works for css file, but no result for javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the paths, I would suggest to use Bottle's `get_url` function.If you publish your application under a directory (f.e. domain.com/app) it won't work.
So better use `src="{{ get_url('static', filename='jquery-ui/jquery-2.1.4.js') }}"`